# Why is concurrent copy of a file not failing?

Tags: python, shutil

I have a simple script that I supposed it was going to fail. 5 processes are trying to copy (using shutil.copy) the same big file to the same destiny (with the same name). I suppose that this will fail because one of the process will open the file to write on it and the rest of the processes will fail as the file was already opened. But this didn't happen and all processes end correctly. I also made an md5 of the copied file, and it seems to be ok.

I want to know if this is a stable behavior or if I'm doing something wrong or odd, to avoid possible errors in the future.

I also tried the same script with another copy functions. With `win32file.CopyFile` the script fails as expected (four processes get an exception: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.).

All tests were made on windows.

Here you can find the script that I'm using:

```
import os
import shutil
import hashlib
import win32file
import multiprocessing
from datetime import datetime

import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

log.addHandler(ch)


NUM_PROCESS = 5
FILE = r"C:\Test\test.txt"


def worker(full_path):
    try:
        worker_name = multiprocessing.current_process().name

        std_path = full_path
        std_dst = r"C:\Test\download\test.txt"

        log.debug("[%s][%s] Copying to: %s to %s", str(datetime.now()), worker_name, std_path, std_dst)
        shutil.copy(std_path, std_dst)
        # win32file.CopyFile(std_path, std_dst, False)
        log.debug("[%s][%s] End copy", str(datetime.now()), worker_name)

        log.info("[%s][%s] Copy hash: %s" % (str(datetime.now()), worker_name, hashfile(open(std_dst, 'rb'),
                                                                                        hashlib.md5())))
        return
    except Exception as e:
        log.error("Can't copy file %s to %s. %s" % (std_path, std_dst, e))


def createEmptyFile(full_path, size):
    try:
        with open(full_path, "wb") as f:
            step = size / 1024 + 1
            if step < 2:
                step = 2
            for _ in xrange(1, step):
                f.write("\0" * 1024)

    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception("Error creating empty file: %s" % e)


def hashfile(afile, hasher, blocksize=65536):
    buf = afile.read(blocksize)
    while len(buf) > 0:
        hasher.update(buf)
        buf = afile.read(blocksize)
    return hasher.hexdigest()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = FILE
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(path))

    if not os.path.exists(FILE):
        log.info("Creating test file")
        createEmptyFile(path, 9589934595)

    log.debug("Creating file hash")
    log.info("Origin hash: %s" % hashfile(open(path, 'rb'), hashlib.md5()))

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(NUM_PROCESS)
    result = pool.map(worker, [path] * NUM_PROCESS)
```

Comment: This seems platform dependent. Add some information on the platform. I know that some of your tests were under Windows, but were all of them?

Comment: I just edited the question, but all tests were made on windows.

Comment: I would *not* expect `shutil.copy` to fail because a copy operation is not expected to fail in POSIX systems (just tested it in a couple of terminals). I understand your expectations under Windows, but... I am not sure on the internals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shutil.copy` function uses `shutil.copyfile` function wich uses simple `open()` ([see sources](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shutil.py#l83))

As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) for `open()` function, it will truncate the file if it already exists. So `open()` allows to write simultaneously to the file and it won't lock it as you might expect.

When the last worker executes `open()` function, it truncates file while other workers continue writing ahead. The last worker adds the data it might truncate and then overwrite all other workers have written. When the first worker finishes copying the file already has all data copied, so calculated hash of copied file should be the same as the origin one. Remain workers just overwrite existing data but file won't change neither its hash.

If you want to lock a file for copying you should use [`flock()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock) on your own.